# Linear Transformation using R2

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $$L: \Bbb R_2 \rightarrow \Bbb R_2 $$ be a linear transformation for which we know that $$L: (\begin{bmatrix}
                 1 & 1\\
                \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
                                  1 & -1\\
                                 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
$$L: (\begin{bmatrix}
                 -1 & 1\\
                \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
                                  2 & 2\\
                                 \end{bmatrix} $$
a) What is $$L:  (\begin{bmatrix}
                 -1 & 5\\
                \end{bmatrix})$$

b) What is  $$L:  (\begin{bmatrix}
                 u & v\\
                \end{bmatrix})$$

I have tried every single other version in my practice problem and I can't get it. I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** Determine the constants $a$ and $b$ such that 
$$
a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  + b \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \phantom{-}1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \phantom{-}5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
(You're simply solving a system of two linear equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$.) You should get $a = 2$, $b=3$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
L\left( \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \phantom{-}5 \end{pmatrix} \right) 
&= L\left( 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  + 3 \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \phantom{-}1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \\ 
&= 2 L \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) + 3 L \left( \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ \phantom{-}1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
&= 2 \begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + 3 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned} 
$$
**(b)** This is similar to part **(a)**. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: How did you get 2 for a and 3 for b?

Comment: Set up an augmented matrix that is equivalent to the system of linear equations. Reduce that matrix to echelon form (or to reduced-row echelon form).

Answer (score 0):

The linear transformation $L$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it has a standard matrix of the form $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$. You know that:
\begin{align*}
L\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a + b\\ c + d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\end{pmatrix}\\
L\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-a + b\\ -c + d\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Therefore you have four equations and four unknowns. By solving these you can figure out what your matrix $A$ is, and then you can easily calculate the values you're after.